# How to run a tensorflow ".pb" file trained on version 1.14.0 on tensorflow version 1.10.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `.pb` file trained on `Tensorflow-GPU==1.14.0`

I want to run the `.pb` file on a `Tensorflow-GPU==1.10.0`

Comment: If you have model code that runs on tf1.10 you can read variable values from the saved model file and hope for the best

Comment: I have a C++ code using Tensorflow 1.10.0, written by someone else who left the company. I did not get, what you mean? Can you explain?